# How do I choose between a Canon 1100D or 700D when I'm overwhelmed by info?

Tags: photography-basics, slr

I am keen to take pictures of food in natural light and now seeking an SLR. I have narrowed it down Canon's 1100D or 700d. There so much info out there, it has made it *more* difficult to choose. What's actually important and how should I weigh various factors in making my choice?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to rephrase your question to make it less specific to right now? Any answers you get probably aren't going to be very useful to readers of the site in a few years, when neither the 1100D nor the 700D are available any more.

Comment: I'm still inclined to see this question as either a duplicate of a more general one or way too localized, even in its current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These cameras are in different Canon ranges, with the 1100D being very much 'entry level' and the 700D being on the upper end of the 'enthusiast' line (before you get into the larger cameras such as 60D and 7D).  Both are fine and capable cameras, however it may be difficult to get the answer you require with relatively little information.

You say you want to take pictures of food in natural light, but in what situations? Static, on a plate, by a window, or in a restaurant, or outdoors, bright or dim natural light?  Or the cooking of the food itself?

Also - are you likely to want to shoot other things too? Holiday, sports, events, people?

On a personal level I would not go with the 1100D simply because I think you would enjoy it for a month or two then as your photography improves, you might find it limited - the low-light capabilities, etc.  I think the 700D would serve you better in respect of the ability to expand your creativity later on.

That said is there a reason you're going for the 700D over the 650D or 600D?  They are both still available I think and still very very good.  The differences between the 650D and 700D are very minor and you might save money with the 650D.

Other than that -- for product photography such as food, I'd invest in a good lens.  A fixed 50mm f/1.8 (or f/1.4), or maybe even the 85mm f/1.8 would serve as good lenses for food photos.

Comment: The amount you can save with the 650D gets you a very nice lens for what I understand to be, in a large sense, trivial differences. Unless one waits, of course. I'd definitely pick the 650D over 600D though.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, buy the cheaper one. Both of those will take excellent pictures. The true quality comes from what you capture with them.